# Generate array of all indexPaths after given indexPath

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewlayout, nsindexpath, flatmap

I'm writing a `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass.

I know how many sections the collection view has... `numberOfSections`.

I know how many items each section has... `numberOfItems[section]`.

Given a starting indexPath `IndexPath(item: x, section: y)` I need to create an array of all indexPaths that come after this starting indexPath.

I tried something like...

```
// iterate all sections
let indexPaths: [IndexPath] = (initialIndexPath.section..<numberOfSections).flatMap { section in
    // find initial item in section
    let initialItemIndex = section == initialIndexPath.section ? initialIndexPath.item + 1 : 0

    // iterate all items in section
    return (initialItemIndex..<(numberOfItems[section] ?? 0)).flatMap { item in
        return IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
    }
}
```

But this tells me (on the second flatMap)...

> 'flatMap' produces '[SegmentOfResult.Iterator.Element]', not the expected contextual result type 'IndexPath?'

I have used something similar to this in another part of the layout and not quite sure why it doesn't work here.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

OK, after a bit of messing around I determined it was down to the way that Swift was inferring the type of the closure.

I fixed it by explicitly setting the type of the first closure from `section in` to `(section) -> ([IndexPath])`

```
// iterate all sections
let indexPaths: [IndexPath] = (initialIndexPath.section..<numberOfSections).flatMap { (section) -> ([IndexPath]) in
    // find initial item in section
    let initialItemIndex = section == initialIndexPath.section ? initialIndexPath.item + 1 : 0

    // iterate all items in section
    return (initialItemIndex..<(numberOfItems[section] ?? 0)).flatMap { item in
        return IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, there are 2 "flatMap" candidates, and the closure type is inferred automatically only for "single-statement closures". – Note that the inner flatMap can be just a map. – Why is `numberOfItems[section]` optional?

Comment: @MartinR it's only optional for now as I used a dictionary to store it. I'll change it eventually. :)